# Change the url that search_form hits during search in Django admin changelist page

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a custom implementation for the changelist page in the Django admin, such that
a custom query parameter is provided in the url. For example, it is like this:

admin/app_label/model_name/?custom_parameter=value

Although I have made the changes I needed to filters and action to work using this url, I have an issue with search. Hitting the search in changelist page, I see that it hits the normal url

admin/app_label/model_name/

. This is an issue since I need the custom parameter in the GET request to appropriately handle things in the django admin backend.

I have also seen the search_form.html file that renders the search element.

Is there a way to define the url that the search will hit, either from the backend or somehow via the javascript of the search_form.html, since I also have the custom_parameter provided in the context of the html page?